# Infinite scrolling with sticky date markers

Tags: jquery, html, infinite-scroll, sticky, jsrender

The page I've created infinitely scrolls through events, grouped chronologically by date. Each date marker can have several subsequent events. While scrolling downward through events for a particular date, the date marker for those events sticks to the top of the page. When a new date marker is reached, the old date marker scrolls off the page and the new date marker sticks in its place.

The problem arises when scrolling upwards, from the bottom of the page to the top. The dates do not consistently stick at the top of the page in the reverse order. What's going wrong?

Please view my code and demonstration, below:

```js
$(function() {
  function addContainers() {
    var nextN = $('.marker-container').length + 1;
    var containers = []

    // Each container has 2 sections now
    for (var i = nextN; i <= nextN + 1; i++) {
      containers.push({
        number: i
      })
    };

    $(".wrapper").html($(".wrapper").html() + $("#template").render(containers));
  }

  function registerMarkers() {
    var collection = $('.marker');

    $.each(collection, function(index, marker) {
      // The last element always does not have a limit
      if (index == collection.length - 1) {
        if ($.isScrollToFixed(marker)) $(marker).trigger('remove.ScrollToFixed');
        $(marker).scrollToFixed();
      } else {
        var nextMarker = $(collection[index + 1]);

        // Skip current, if it and the following one are already registered
        if ($.isScrollToFixed(marker) && $.isScrollToFixed(nextMarker)) return true;
        // On this stage we have all unregistered markers and the last registered one, which precedes the first unregistered marker.

        var nextMarkerC = nextMarker.parent(); // For offsets we rely on stable position of marker container

        $(marker).scrollToFixed({
          limit: nextMarkerC.offset().top - 100
        });
      }
    });
  }

  addContainers();
  registerMarkers();

  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    // If we reached the end of window
    if (document.body.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).height()) {
      addContainers();
      registerMarkers();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.marker {
  position: absolute; // This is important!
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 98px;
  border: 3px dashed red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.section {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 3px #666 dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>

<body>

  <script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="marker-container">
      <div class="marker">Date {{>number}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">One event</div>
    <div class="section">Another event</div>
  </script>

  <div class="wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

[See code and demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYpG/68/).

Comment: Please include at least the JavaScript from your Fiddle in your question as well. Fiddles can expire, which means this question will be useuless to someone later should that happen.

Comment: The problem was difficult to understand. I tried to clarify by describing the problem in more detail and creating a runnable snippet to demonstrate. I hope I got it right.